# Cannot active plugin dgit because it's not registered yet in remix.ethereum (cannot find DGIT module, VIPER module)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to connect my smart contract deployed in remix.ethereum to my github, but i am unable to connect my ide to github because i cannot see DGIT module in plugin manager. once i tried to change the workspace i am getting's this message

> Cannot active plugin dgit because it's not registered yet

i viewed documentation but i still cannot solve the issue. i tried to clone a git repo in remix ide - but i still face same issue again, so i cannot clone repo or push my ide repo to github. how to activate DGIT module which is not even displayed in my plugin manager? and also to clone git repo

DGIT module not registered msg

[image]

My plugin manager

[image]

I tried to change different workspace but still facing same issue. I am not able to find documents regarding this issue, and cannot clone git repo.  I am also not able to see DGIT module in plug in manager. I cannot view any other modules in plugin manager (Eg..Viper, etherscan, dgit) so i need solution to overcome this issue